# How to redirect to a root file as non-root with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

How to do that with a regular sudoers user:

```sh
wget -q https://example.com/binary.tar.gz -O - | tar -xzO binary > /usr/local/bin/binary # Doesn't work because I can't write in /usr/local/bin as regular user
```

I can't use sudo with the redirect `>`. So what is the appropriate way to do it?

Subsidiary question: I know I can use tee for the following case:

```sh
echo "foo" > /etc/myapp.conf # Doesn't work
echo "foo" | sudo tee -a /etc/myapp.conf # Solution
```

But I know this is not the goal of tee. So the question is the same for this case: what's the best solution?

**EDIT**:

- I don't want to use a subshell with something like `sudo sh -c 'my-command'`. One reason is to limit as much as possible the number of commands launched as root.
- This is a question to find a solution in the "linux standard", not some kind of hacking.
- I think the goal of tee is to write output to some files AND in the stdout. I don't want to use something which can do that, but something which exists to do that.

Comment: "I know this is not the goal of tee" -- why do you say that? This is a perfectly valid use of tee.

Comment: Yes, it's a valid use of tee, but this is not the main goal of tee which is designed to output to some files AND in the stdout (like a `T` I guess).

Answer (score 3):

The reason you cannot redirect to a file you don't have write access to, is because the shell does the opening of the file. When using `sudo` only the process that are ran with special privileges, consider the following example:

```
$ sudo my-cmd --flag1 --flag2 > file
```

The shell invokes the command `sudo` with the arguments: `my-cmd`, `--flag1` and `--flag2`, and tries to open a file called `file`, and connect the sudo process' standard output to the input of the file.

The command `sudo` will elevate the users permissions and execute the command `my-cmd` with the arguments `--flag1` and `--flag2`.

Understanding this it also becomes clear why you cannot just prefix with `sudo` to write to a file that you don't have permissions to.

Instead you can, as you have already discovered, use `tee` as it can take a path as an argument and open it for writing.

Alternative you can invoke another shell with special privileges:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'my-cmd --flag1 --flag2 > file'
```

This will invoke the shell `sh` with escalated privileges. This however becomes quite tedious as you'll need to stick your whole command into one argument for `sh`. This will cause quotes and glob to be hard to write properly.

Comment: Thanks @andlrc. Yes, I know why it does not work, I just want to find a "clean solution". I edited my post to explain I don't want to use a subshell. I hope there is a solution similar to tee.